Drop-in replacement for the cgi module
Python 3.13 removed the cgi module.
While there are many ways described how to workaround that issue, e.g. via using urllib and the email package, for one project I actually need a drop-in replacement, that is a package which also offers a FieldStorage class which I can use instead of the removed one.
I have read about such a project a few weeks ago, but unfortunately did not bookmark it.
tl/dr

I look for a package which offers a FieldStorage class as a replacement for the removed cgi.FieldStorage in Python 3.13.
I am not interested in ways to rewrite the code via urllib and the email package
Werkzeug is not a drop-in replacement

Thank you!

Did you consider copying the cgi.py file (maybe edited to contain the FieldStorage class only) from Python's stdlib ver. 3.12 into your project?

Thanks, that is a good suggestion, but then I would need to maintain that code myself. And I think there are many people out there which are in the same boat, so an external library would be the best fit for that - which I have found. I will add an answer in a minute.

It seems other people had the same need.
The Python CGI package is a drop-in replacement for the cgi package, which was removed from Python 3.13 onwards.
https://github.com/jackrosenthal/python-cgi
In order to use it, you only have to
pip install legacy-cgi

There are no code changes required.
