"No module named 'cgi'" when trying to make a request in Python
While executing the below code :
import requests
response=requests.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json")
response.raise_for_status()

Throws the below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91755\PycharmProjects\Day-33\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\91755\PycharmProjects\Day-33\.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\91755\PycharmProjects\Day-33\.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cgi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'

How to resolve this error?
Try to install CGI package but its not work.

What are your python and requests versions? What happens if you run your script in a terminal (i.e., not in PyCharm)?

I guess that you use Python 3.13. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78635741/drop-in-replacement-for-the-cgi-module
